# IRC library in C#

Tags: c#, client, irc

I want to embed a small chat window in my program that will function as a basic IRC client.  This requires limited functionality such as connecting, disconnecting, listing users, and sending private messages.

As of writing, I have tried several bloated libraries that make it too difficult to create a simple application (wiring many events, handling things like channels, modes, etc. that I'm not interested in).  Other libraries I've tried are developed for old versions of .NET and are full of deprecation warnings.  How can I develop a lightweight IRC client in C#?

Comment: any full sample code ?

Comment: I know we can look at the documentation on codeplex for IrcDotNet version 0.3 at https://ircdotnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/50632 or the samples at https://ircdotnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/50639.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two years later, now there's [ircdotnet](https://github.com/IrcDotNet/IrcDotNet) which seems to work pretty well.

Should note that this does not yet (and will likely never) work for Windows 8 Metro-style (WinRT) apps.

Comment: Indeed. I must point out the Launchpad site is always going to have the latest code and releases... alas the GitHub mirror isn't quite up and running yet!

Comment: Edited in, thanks for the update! Any chance you'll have a WinRT/Metro version available? I've tried linking in the current (well, current last March) version to the developer preview and Visual Studio would have none of it.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I've sort of moved away from that area, and am gravitating towards Mono/Mac as my primary platform these days. I intend to keep up full support for standard .NET version though -- and perhaps WinRT in the future, if people really need it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a bunch of IRC libraries on Codeplex, one of them which seems quite good is Nebo IRC: http://nebo.codeplex.com/

Some other IRC libraries on Codeplex: http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?projectSearchText=IRC

Comment: any full sample code ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the protocol is so simple you probably could do it yourself then. Really, I've tested some years ago using simply telnet! I'd get the source of some simple client and just implement the same commands.

You can refer to: http://www.irchelp.org/irchelp/rfc/rfc.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using this C# IRC Library:
http://www.meebey.net/projects/smartirc4net/

It has many methods, I'm sure you can achieve everything you want with them:
http://smartirc4net.meebey.net/docs/0.4.0/html/

Projects using SmartIrc4net

- Smuxi IRC Client
- SparkleShare
- Low Orbit Ion Cannon
- MonkeyWrench
- U-Lyss IRC-Bot
- DG Network
- Abbot
- Spike.NET
- Prelude Chatbot
- VandalSniper

References: [Get users list of a given channel in IRC server using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343318/get-users-list-of-a-given-channel-in-irc-server-using-c-sharp)