# Get users list of a given channel in IRC server using C#

Tags: c#, message, irc

I use VS 2010 in Win7.
I want use IRC programatically, using IRC client library in C# for

- Connect to an IRC server
- Detect if exists a channel in IRC server
- Get Users list of a given channel in a IRC Server.
- Send messages to a user in a given channel and receive messages from a user (mantenain conversation)

any suggestions about it ? full source code sample ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this C# IRC Library:
http://www.meebey.net/projects/smartirc4net/

It has many methods, I'm sure you can achieve everything you want with them:
http://smartirc4net.meebey.net/docs/0.4.0/html/