# How to bind Mirc to Visual Studio in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, dll, mirc

I am working on a game in unity and it requires some kind of chat client. I have to bind mIRC to Visual Studio and Unity so I can begin the next phase, coding the client. I am having issues with finding a tutorial since this is kind of a complicated situation.

I chose mIRC so I don't have to reinvent the wheel completely with a chat client and it looks prettier than what I can do. I want to do this in C# since I am very familiar with this language. I tried searching the internet for tutorials on how to do so but none of them suit my needs.

At the end, I want to have a DLL ready so Visual Studio can communicate with Unity and mIRC.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962075/irc-library-in-c-sharp

Comment: It is not a duplicate because I have a list of software that I want to use to make a DLL. Just unsure of how to bind them together.

Comment: You...want to embed the actual mIRC client into your own application? Or...what?

Comment: @Ben That is a part of what I want. I wanted to make a DLL so I can make scripts in Visual Studio so it can communicate with mIRC.

Comment: Question edit: I changed the last sentence to add some more clarification.

Comment: I think you're making life difficult on yourself. You can find c# irc clients you can reference, or build something using signalr. Literally thousands of tutorials and example projects along with a heap of ready to go nuget packages and libraries. If you really want to do it this way though, this is old but worth trying: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523669/how-to-write-and-send-text-to-mirc-in-c-win32

Comment: I agree with Ben : this is going about it the wrong way and making life hard. In software dev we don't look around for some example of a full blown app that we would use standalone and then try to work out a way to control it from c#- we look for a library written in .net and shared/sold, so we could import it and get it to do the donkey work

Comment: @Ben Took a look at Signalr and decided to use that instead! Thanks! This helps a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Your question isn't 100% clear, is this what you mean?...

It sounds like you want to embed a mIRC window in your application...

The easiest way would be to get mIRC to load a DLL of yours, then use that interface to get the hwnd of a window via the mIRC $window alias (or similar).

Once you have that, you should be able to embed the window within your own app (and potentially hide the rest of mIRC) using Windows APIs.